# Sub basis for a product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $(X,\tau_x)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be two topological spaces. Consider $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ and $\pi_X: X\times Y \to X$ and $\pi_Y: X \times Y \to Y$ be the natural projections map. Then is $\mathcal S= \{\pi_X^{-1}(U) ,\pi_Y^{-1}(V)\}$ a sub-basis for the product topology on $X\times Y$ ?

Comment: No.  Two sets will usually not make a subbase.

Comment: With U and V open in X and Y, respectively, then yes, and you can find a proof for this in Munkres, Theorem 15.2.

Comment: They are not open. But their union gives the whole set. So shouldn't the set of all finite intersections give me a basis?

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi.  U and V are two sets and the two sets you suggest is not a subbase.  You need to clarify within the {...} notation if U and V are a range of sets or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the definition of the product topology says that

$$\mathcal{S} = \{\pi_Y^{-1}[U]: V \subseteq Y \text{ open }\} \cup \{\pi_X^{-1}[U]:  U \subseteq X \text{ open }\}$$

is a subbase for the product topology on $X \times Y$.

For general products $X = \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ the subbase is:

$$\bigcup_{i \in I}\{\pi_i^{-1}[U]: U \subseteq X_i \text{ open }\}$$

where $\pi_i: X \to X_i$ is the projection.

Comment: Is the condition that the sub-sets should be open necessary?

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi Yes, absolutely. We want to make the projections continuous, and do no more than necessary.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was going through Munkres and trying to figure out what his definition of subbasis is . Is the definition equivalent to saying "intersection of subbasis elements generates basis elements?" If that is the case, then I dont understand why for the finite product topology ( say X x Y ) he defines the subbasis as preimage of open set of X union with preimage of open set of Y. If we take R^2 as an example, would something like (0,3) x (Y) be an element of the subbasis or does it have to be something like [(0,3) x (Y) union (X) x (1,2)]?

Comment: @willyx888 no, the subbase elements are all sets of the form $\pi^{-1}[O]$ where $\pu$ is any projection and $O$ an appropriate open set. No unions. So the former not the latter.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ok thats what i thought it should be. So this statement here: S={π^−1Y[U]:V⊆Y open }∪{π^−1X[U]:U⊆X open }, just means the collection of all projection preimage of X and Y?

Comment: @willyx888 yes, the two types for each projection taken together as one collection of subsets. So the union is at the family of sets level, not in the product itself.